# Crystal Report how to ignore certain rows when one of the criteria matches

Tags: crystal-reports

i've just started on Crystal Reports and just gotten the basics of it at the moment, however it seems that i got caught up in one part where i'm stuck at the moment.

I've created a selection clause and managed to get as close as I could for this report.

```
{table.status} = 'O' and
{table.date} = currentdate - 1
```

here's an example with the results that come up

```
`account | ir_num`   

`100123  | null`

`100123  | 1223`

`100124  | null`

`100125  | null`
```

this is due to the table having both null values and running number values on the ir_num column. what i'd like to display is that if there are two same account numbers and if one of them even displays the ir_num column with a value inside, i'll then take it and ignore the null ones.

So basically the ideal one should look like this

```
`account | ir_num`   

`100123  | 1223`

`100124  | null`

`100125  | null`
```

Would highly appreciate if someone could guide me through on how to get this up and running. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to group on the account number and hide the details.  Then, instead of showing the ir_num field itself, show the maximum for the group.  (You may need to convert the nulls to `0` to properly sort, I'm not in front of a Crystal install at the moment.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however it seems that i'm still unable to obtain the information that i need though even though i've grouped it together. upon grouping there are some account number that has ir_num but not showing this time.

Comment: Are you using a formula instead of the "raw" ir_num value?  For example: `if IsNull({ir_num}) then 0 else {ir_num}`.  Take the max of that and you'll get a value for any account number that has a value (or 0 for an account number with only null(s)).

Comment: ah! i manage to get it i think, just to confirm if i'm right, basically i switch all nulls to 0, then i group it by account and place everything onto the header, then i do a sort to ensure the invoice numbers appear that if they have and if not, the 0 would then appear. i got the result i wanted but just wanna make sure my understand is correct, thank you for helping again though! this gives me new ideas on how i can build my next report

Comment: Yes!  That is exactly what I was trying to say.  The only difference is that you don't need to worry about sorting, you can just show the maximum value of the ir_num formula for each account in the header.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! this definitely helps in multiple ways ;) sorry for the late reply though! gonna mark this as answer!